# Eliminating duplicates Q

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I had a task from one course on Udemy to create a program which eliminates duplicates from array and i failed so I have looked to my instructors code and I don't understand few things.

1. Why don't you have to write the capacity of array (function input) ? it is because of that you already has written the elements of array so it was recognized how long it is ?
2. the if statement for not true Boolean: the counter is initialized to zero so for the first time when unique_data[counter++]=numbers[i=0] is counter also zero a then it is incremented ?

sorry for asking these questions but I am little bit worried that i have not been able to solve this myself

```
void unique_numbers( int numbers[], unsigned int collection_size){
    
    
   int unique_data [20];


   unsigned int unique_counter{};//Initialized to zero. Counts the elements we have in 
                                //the unique_data array

   for(unsigned int i{}; i < collection_size; ++i){

    bool already_in{false};

    //See if  the element is not already in our unique_data
    for(unsigned int j{};j < unique_counter; ++j){
        
      
      if(unique_data[j] == numbers[i]){
        already_in = true;
        break;
      }
    }

   
    if(!already_in){
      unique_data[unique_counter++] = numbers[i];
    }
    
  }

  std::cout << "The collection contains " << unique_counter << " unique numbers, they are : ";

  for(unsigned int i{};i < unique_counter ; ++i){
    std::cout << unique_data[i] << " ";
  }
```

Comment: Suggest using `std::array<>` (or `std::vector<>`) instead of plain arrays whenever you can.

Comment: Also, this might go against the idea of the task, but copying the data to a set, then moving the set to an array will get you what you need (and it's sort of quick).

Comment: I've tested it and on small datasets it seems to work; however, on large datasets it's UB as there might be more than 20 unique number.

Comment: What is the intended audience for you Udemy course? You are asking a basic question that's covered in every introductory C++ textbook. If your Udemy course is ostensibly for someone who has no prior knowledge of C++ either: you skipped some crucial introductory information, or the course is crap. I'm leaning towards the "crap" explanation; if this is a verbatim code sample from the course.

Comment: *Why don't you have to write the capacity of array ?* The capacity of `unique_data` is hard-coded to 20, so there isn't much need to track. The number of items in `unique_data` is tracked with `unique_counter`. As Lorro points out, if this number reaches  20, `unique_data` is full. The program needs a test for this to prevent overflow.

Comment: @user4581301 -- it's fairly obvious to me that the array whose capacity was questioned is the function's parameter. It looks like an array. But it has no given capacity.

Comment: Ok, thank you I will look at it. But can you explain me more your solution to this task with copying ? I am beginner in c++ same like as the programming itself. Talking about the lenght, i know that 20 is a little bit small range, so is there some standard value for this when you don´t know how long it´s going to be ?

Comment: Sam Varshavchik : It supposed to be for the beginners. Talking about the incremented value it is my fault, I´ve did not realized it for the first time when i was writting this. And if you are asking if this is a solution from instructor so yes it is

Comment: The standard solution when you don't know how large an array must be is covered int he first comment.

Comment: If the question your asking is “why isn’t there a number between the brackets in the array in the function parameter” the answer is 3 fold. First, the size of the array is the next parameter. 2nd it’s not between the brackets because that isn’t how c++ works. 3rd it’s not an array. As Sam pointed out, either you haven’t reached this information yet, or you skipped over it/didn’t fully understand it.

Comment: user4581301 : ok thanks for your answers, Now I think I got it. Still I am little bit upset that I did not handle this myself, time to replay some vid and open book.

Comment: Taekahn : yeah i understand that, My Q was that you don´t have to add the 2nd  parameter (collection_size)  if you add the first one( int numbers[] ) . Sorry my english is not as good so maybe that is the reason of misunderstanding.

Comment: Sorry to break the bad news to you, but this instructor does not know what they're doing. I've browsed though Udemy's offerings, when $dayjob$ was paying for it. Udemy is teeming with self-promoting former used car salesmen that sell themselves as the smartest people alive. They're not. This instructor should've explained this basic concept, what function parameters that are specified as arrays, with or without a size, really are. Spoiler alert: they're not arrays. Unfortunately, Stackoverflow is not a C++ textbook replacement, where these basic topics are fully explained.

Comment: Sam Varshavchik : Ok thank you for your feedback, i know that i was asking basic Q.  I will keep it in mind for the future. Recently i have bought some textbooks so I will learn from more sources next time before I bother someone.

Comment: @PetrMáša [See this example](https://godbolt.org/z/7KT49vTfa)

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your program with std::vector and std::find . The logic is the same. Now it is more readable. Hope you will understand it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>


void unique_numbers(int numbers[], unsigned int collection_size)
{
    std::vector<int> unique_data;
    for (unsigned int i{}; i < collection_size; ++i)
    {
        //Find numbers[i] in unique_data. If it is not found insert it in unique_data
        auto it = std::find(unique_data.begin(), unique_data.end(), numbers[i]);
        if (it == unique_data.end()) 
        {
            unique_data.push_back(numbers[i]);
        }
    }

    //print unique_data vector
    std::cout << "The collection contains " << unique_data.size() << " unique numbers, they are : ";
    for (const auto& v : unique_data){
        std::cout << v << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    
}

int main()
{
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };
    unsigned int n = sizeof(a)/sizeof(int);
    unique_numbers(a, n);
}
```